# jQuery wrap attribute inside span

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, attributes

I have this code that changes the image's attribute to the `data-title` attribute:

```js
$(currentSelection).closest(".img-to-select").prevAll(".custom-title").find("span").html($(currentSelection).children("img").attr("data-title"));
```

How do make it so that when changing this attribute, it is displayed in the `span` tag?

If I just add it to the end of `.append($("<span>"))`:

```
.attr("data-title")).append($("<span>"));
```

Then my `span` is displayed separately, not around my value with `data-title`.

**html**

```
<div class="custom-title">
   @if($loop->first)
      <span>
         @if(!empty($image->title))
            <span>{{ $image->title }}</span>
         @endif
      </span>
   @endif
</div>
```

Comment: So you want a new span nested inside the span that `.find()` returned?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, there should be a `span` inside the `span`, I can show the html, maybe it will become clearer

Comment: @Barmar I added, `$image->title` this is my `data-title`

Comment: @Barmar But when switching the `data-title`, the `span` flies, and in the script I need to make sure that the `data-title` is inside the `span`

Comment: `.find('span')` will find both spans in the original HTML. I think you want `.children('span')` to just find the first level span.

Comment: Or you could use `.find('span > span')` and then just set its HTML, so you don't need to add a new span.

Comment: @Barmar Can I display all this only if `data-title` is not empty? 
It's the html part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `$('<span>')` inside the `.html()`, not append after it.

```
let title = $(currentSelection).children('img').data('title');
if (title) {
    $(currentSelection).closest('.img-to-select')
        .prevAll('.custom-title').find('span')
        .html($('<span>', {html: title}));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. And another question, is it possible to check right here in the script that if the `data-title` is empty, then do not display anything?

Comment: You don't need to check that, it will just be an empty string and that's what it will display. Do you mean you want to leave the old HTML unchanged?

Comment: Just for the second `span`, I set styles with a colored background, and if there is an empty string, then only an empty colored background will be displayed, here is such a problem

Comment: You can simply wrap an `if` statement around the whole code: `if ($(currentSelection).children('img').data('title'))`

Comment: syntax error occurs

Comment: after this `{html:`

Comment: I can't reproduce that error.

Comment: I've added the `if` statement to my answer. I suspect you put it in the wrong place.

Comment: yes, it's clear now, thanks